# Unsolvable wow problems

Tags: wine, games

I have direct rendering enabled on my ati radeon 4200
I have changed all of my registry and game settings to make it work correctly and well.
BUT WoW still wont run past 8 fps. I honestly have no other ideas Ive searched all over google and tried everything. Ive heard wow usually runs better on wine then on windows and i was getting 30-50 fps on windows so I would imagine id at least be able to get 20-60 on wine. Im also running ubuntu 12.04 64bit and have installed all drivers and latest catalyst update.

Comment: Did you setup it using winetricks?

Comment: can you link to a tut? all i did to play was copy from my windows partion to my external ssd and then copied back to wines folder

Comment: Here is a link to know more about winetricks http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks/ .This article may come in handy http://v.gd/4Jmoyz

Answer (score 0):

Open `config.wtf` and add this line:

```
SET gxapi "OpenGL"
```

Comment: i did this and there was no improvement

Comment: Ive had this same issue when i I had ATI. What is your card model?

Comment: i have the ati radeon 4200

Comment: Hit your Catalyst panel. OpenGL settings, Kill AA to 1x, Kill sync to Vblank -> Save and close. update driver. That GX api trick should have done it. In fact... theres nothing more that can be done if youve already dont the wineHQ tricks

Comment: Whoah wait a tick. Is that the 4200 Onboard?

Comment: yes it is onboard

Comment: Desktop... or laptop?

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question it is not quite clear what this command does. Please elaborate your answer adding explanations.